# (Unity2D) How to disable an object not in view port with added tolerance? And re-enable when in view

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have written a code that allows me to disable objects when they are not in the viewport using the following code:

```
//Script to disable objects not in view. We can use tolerance for it too.
//[Range(0, 100)]
//public float Tolerance = 5;

private void LateUpdate()
{
    Vector2 pos = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(transform.position);

    //MMDebug.DrawCube(transform.position, MMColors.GhostWhite, new Vector2(Tolerance, Tolerance));


    if (pos.x >= 0.0f && pos.x <= 1.0f && pos.y >= 0.0f && pos.y <= 1.0f)
    {
        Debug.Log("You can see me!");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("You cannot see me!");
    }
}
```

This code works well, however, I want to add a tolerance to it for how big an object might be. And it should also re-activate the object when in view port.

Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not use the built-in methods? [`isVisible`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-isVisible.html).

Comment: @TEEBQNE I tried that but it does not help. Since the game object became inactive, it cannot be re-activated when it enters view again.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually calculate if an object is in the Cameras frustrum using [`GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes.html) and [`GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB.html)

```c#
[SerializeField] private Camera _cam;
[SerializeField] private Renderer _renderer;

private void LateUpdate()
{
    if(!_renderer) _renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    if(!_cam) _cam = Camera.main;

    var planes = GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes(cam);

    _renderer.enabled = GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB(planes, _renderer.bounds)
}
```

You could also visualize these bounds for debugging using e.g.

```c#
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif

...

#if UNITY_EDITOR
private void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    if(!_renderer) _renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();

    if (!_renderer) return;

    var bounds = _renderer.bounds;
 
    Gizmos.color = Color.green;
    Gizmos.DrawWireCube(bounds.center, bounds.size);
    Gizmos.color = Color.yellow;
    Gizmos.DrawSphere(bounds.center, bounds.size.magnitude * 0.1f);
}
#endif
```

Comment: But this checks the renderer, which would be deactivated when out of view. Will it still work when the object comes back into view? Because I need the object to reactivate when back into view

Comment: @A.H.Alwagdani I added a method for visualizing the bounds in the scene view. The `Renderer.bounds` basically is just a bounding box containing the transformed `Mesh.bounds`. afaik it is available also if the renderer is disabled since it is just a pure maths based structure